# How to set the clipboard sharing mode to one-way only in vmware workstation/player

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, clipboard, vmware-tools

I noticed that VMware's clipboard sharing is a two-way sharing, but because I often run dangerous software in the virtual machine, I don't want the dangerous software inside the virtual machine to read my host's clipboard. But I need the host to read the clipboard inside the virtual machine.

I tried to turn off the `client isolation - enable copy and paste` option, but it will also prevent the host from reading the clipboard inside the virtual machine. I don't want to do this.

I tried to add `isolation.tools.paste.disable = true` to the .vmx file of the virtual machine, but it didn't work.

What should I do? Thank you for your reply.